# Оптимизация использования дисплея в Elementary OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, оптимизация, elementary-os

Как совместить окно приложения и верхнюю строку в Elementary OS. необходимо потому что, экран ноутбука маленький хотелось бы больше. Буду благодарен даже если подскажите в какую сторону капать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставить awesome в качестве window manager.

Answer (score 2):

В любом браузере есть F11 для полноэкранного режима - удобно когда работаете со одной вкладкой. В фаерфоксе давлением мышки ввех можно достать открытые вкладки.

В старом фаерфоксе был флаг в about:config для сокрытия декорации. Браузеры Opera, Chrome, Yandex, Vivaldi скрывают заголовок когда развернуты.

Для оригинального гнома 3 есть расширение https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/
но я не уверен что оно запустится на элементари.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, точно не знаю как это можно реализовать. Но могу подсказать с направлением.
1. Вы можете поискать как поставить `global menu` как тут: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/31er5c/global_menu_in_elementary/
Если все правильно настроите ,то меню настроек типа "Файл, Настройки и тп" переместится на верхний `bar`. Вам останется лишь сменить тему `window manager` на какую-нибудь минималистичную.
2. Сменить `window manager` на какой-нибудь `awesome wm`.
3. Поискать минималистичные темы типа `xenlism`

Comment: натягивать овсом поверх третьегнома - то ещё извращение.)

Comment: @eri, при использовании awesome Gnome в принципе не нужен.

Comment: @0andriy, холивар конечно, но я не только о менеджере окон, в гном еще входит дюжина программ.

Comment: Это не гном. Вернее, сессия гнома, а шелл - от elementaryos.

Comment: @Ancient там много от гнома

Comment: @eri, нет. Немного. Большая часть - самописные приложения.

Comment: С теми же широкими панелями